# Halyard Deploy Spinnaker Target

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, spinnaker-halyard

Am trying to deploy spinnaker using halyard. We have 20-25 application clusters ( Azure AKS clusters ) where we want to deploy applications from spinnaker. We also have a spinnaker cluster where i want to deploy spinnaker.

I have configured app and spinnaker clusters using hal. How do i get hal deploy spinnaker in spinnaker cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Spinnaker Operator is available for kubernetes now. You can install it as CRD on your cluster , take a look here https://operatorhub.io/operator/spinnaker-operator and see the install instructions.